# About smoothstate reverse animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a website and I've decided to insert smoothstate.js into it. I've followed a guide on how to install it and I was able to, but I've got only one problem. When the page is loaded the intro animation is executed but, when i click on a link and load another page, there is no animation (which should be the reverse of the intro's one). I can't see where's my mistake, could you help me? Here is my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/servizi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/pagetransition.css">
<title>Htmldesign.it - Web and Visual Designer</title>


</head>

<body>    
    <div id="wrapper" class="m-scene">
    <!--Header-->    
        <header>

        <div id="logo">
                <a href="../index.html"><img src="../Images/logo.png" alt="htmldesign.it"></a>           
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html"><span>HOMEPAGE</span></a></li>  
                <li><a href="servizi.html">SERVIZI</a></li>  
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>  
                <li><a href="contatti.html">CONTATTI</a></li>   
           </ul>
        </nav>

        </header>

        <section id="main"  class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinleft">
            <div>.....other things....</div>     
        </section>  

    <div class="pushfooter"></div>
    </div>      
    </div> 

    <!--Footer-->  
    <footer>
  /**/
    </footer>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.smoothState.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/menuservizi.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/function.js" language="javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

pagetransition.css
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

```
/* line 6, /Users/mperez/Sites/smoothstate/source/stylesheets/pageTransitions.css.scss */
.m-scene .scene_element {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; }
/* line 22, /Users/mperez/Sites/smoothstate/source/stylesheets/pageTransitions.css.scss */
.m-scene .scene_element--fadeinup {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp; }
.m-scene .scene_element--fadeinout {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInOut;
  animation-name: fadeInOut; }
/* line 27, /Users/mperez/Sites/smoothstate/source/stylesheets/pageTransitions.css.scss */
.m-scene .scene_element--fadeinright {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight; }
.m-scene .scene_element--fadeinleft {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  animation-name: fadeInLeft; }
/* line 38, /Users/mperez/Sites/smoothstate/source/stylesheets/pageTransitions.css.scss */
.m-scene.is-exiting .scene_element {
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;zz
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse; }

function.js
    ;(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var $body    = $('html, body'), // Define jQuery collection 
      content  = $('#main').smoothState({
        onStart : {
          duration: 250,
          render: function () {
            content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');

            // Scroll user to the top
            $body.animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 });

          }
        }
      }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:
This morning I was able to figure out the mistake, but now  there is another one: this is the site in which I'm working on : http://www.htmldesign.it 
The problem is that the smoothstate works only when I click on a link that redirect on the same page, in fact it does the reverse animation. Otherwise when I click on a link for another page, the reverse animation does not work. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the smoothstate demo on the authors site, he uses an outdated jQuery function: `.toggleAnimationClass()` . He's updated the github documentation and in his examples, in the `onStart` property, he adds an `is-exiting` class and then calls:

```
smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
```

to restart the animation. You'll still need to tell the animations to go in reverse in the CSS. It should look like this:

```
.m-scene.is-existing{
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

Here's a recent guide on how to [implement it on a site.](http://hirecollin.com/2016/05/integrating-smoothstate-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally wasn't able to get the reverse animation to work, but for animation on each page you have to put your

`<div id="wrapper" class="m-scene">`

and

`<section id="main"  class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinleft">`

on every page you want animated.

Here's a great video that got me on the right path:
[Smoothstate.js tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HKPPdVGXCQ)

PS. I think `id="main"` should be on the outer `"wrapper"` rather then where it is now.

Answer (score 0):

This got me, too. You need to add the "Exit" animation state to your CSS. For example:

```
.m-scene.is-exiting .scene_element {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn; // These lines
    animation-name: zoomIn;         // These lines
}
```

Whatever animation you wish to run when you exit the page should be here (I used `zoomIn`). Good luck!

Comment: Make sure you're you've added CSS for the animation itself. Eg: `-webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;`